# Software crash : drivers issue?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a software which keep crashing and I can't get a finger on why. I have written to the game developpers and they've told me that is a driver issue. Any idea how to fix it ?

```
 $ inxi -SPARM -GCDN -v1 -xGCRS
System:    Host: msi Kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GF65 Thin 9SEXR v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16W1 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends 
           v: E16W1IMS.108 date: 12/04/2019 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-9300H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38400 
           Speed: 3582 MHz min/max: 800/4100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3342 2: 3548 3: 3172 4: 3532 5: 3572 6: 3260 7: 3125 
           8: 3551 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia v: 460.56 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~120Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2060/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.56 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-48-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 404.31 GiB (84.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLQ512HALU-00000 size: 476.94 GiB 
RAID:      Message: No RAID data was found. 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 404.30 GiB (86.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Info:      Processes: 280 Uptime: 36m Memory: 7.62 GiB used: 1.50 GiB (19.7%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 
           Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

```
# journalctl output at time of crash
  -----------------
Apr 03 00:08:29 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:29 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:31 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:31 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:31 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:31 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:31 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Successfully made thread 4788 of process 4703 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Apr 03 00:08:31 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:31 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:31 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:32 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:32 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:34 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Apr 03 00:08:34 msi rtkit-daemon[1214]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
```

```
 $ cat /home/brieucdug/.config/unity3d/VelociDrone/VelociDrone/Player.log

blablabla
# (...)
blablabla

Receiving unhandled NULL exception
#0  0x000000010ea398 in std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
#1  0x00000001116812 in std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
#2  0x000000009298d6 in std::pow(float, float)
#3  0x0000000092660b in std::pow(float, float)
#4  0x000000009232a2 in std::pow(float, float)
#5  0x000000009233d9 in std::pow(float, float)
#6  0x00000000cbb720 in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#7  0x007fe0d6f50609 in start_thread
#8  0x007fe0d6e75293 in clone
```

Nothing on `dmesg`

Output of `sudo nvidia-bug-report.sh` : https://filebin.net/m7s1o6z6rcu1lry7

---

Any hint where to look ? Should I try to contact nvidia ?

---

#### Requested

```
 $ ls -al /var/crash
total 4316
drwxrwsrwt  2 root      whoopsie    4096 Mar 26 19:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root      root        4096 Apr 23  2020 ..
-rw-r-----  1 brieucdug whoopsie 4404925 Mar 26 19:17 _usr_bin_nvidia-settings.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 brieucdug whoopsie       0 Mar 26 19:17 _usr_bin_nvidia-settings.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie  whoopsie      37 Mar 26 19:17 _usr_bin_nvidia-settings.1000.uploaded
```

#### upgrade nvidia drivers and kernel

I reproduced several times the crash, always the same things.

I also found : https://forum.unity.com/threads/linux-the-build-crashes-after-a-few-hours-receiving-unhandled-null-exception.989004/ ;
I did unable "trail" but it didn't change anything, crashed again. All other settings of particle are OFF as well.

Comment: Does this occur when running on the Intel or Nvidia? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: @heynnema there is nothing from yesterday / I'm not sure what the March 26th crash is about.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a possible Nvidia driver problem.

There's a newer driver available.

You have version 460.56. The newer one is 460.67, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

**Update #1:**

Micro-Star product: GF65 Thin 9SEXR

You have an older BIOS version E16W1IMS.108 dated: 12/04/2019. BIOS version E16W1IMS.10B dated: 2020-10-14 is available [here](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GF65-Thin-9SX?sub_product=GF65-Thin-9SEXR).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: Hello. Thanks, I have upgraded. Sadly it doesn't work :(

Comment: @B.duGaray "It doesn't work" means what? Please give more details.

Comment: It means I crashed again with the exact same logs several times to make sure, after rebooting. I also found that. I deleted all particles I could find in my settings but it didn't work neither. https://forum.unity.com/threads/linux-the-build-crashes-after-a-few-hours-receiving-unhandled-null-exception.989004/ ; I'll add that to my post when I get to my computer. Thanks for your input

Comment: @B.duGaray Does the software that's crashing work if you select the Intel video card? Explain what "particles" is. What software are we talking about?

Comment: that is a fpv racing simulator. It works but with 9 to 12 fps, I can't do anything with this :/ ; particles are graphics artefacts in Unity3D engine. Like Sunbeam in some games

Comment: @B.duGaray (third request...) Does this software work with the Intel video without crashing?

Comment: I didn't have the hobby to test. It's unplayable with a dozen frame per second, and I guess my computer would become really hot. I can try in the days to come to wait it to crash on intel.

Comment: @B.duGaray Please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Arg. I don't think I'm gonna be able (take the risk) to update bios before this summer , since I'll have lots of important exams. Thanks for the information